# Sending json post request in thirdparty api from sketchup

Tags: ruby, post, sketchup

I am trying to send a post request from sketchup to the api i made.I have web dialog.On the web dialog,On click the “save” button the post request will be executed.I want to send the information as json.I have been able to access the api i made.How can i access the length,width and send the length,width,volume from the sketchup model as json.here is the model i wrote::

```
  def self.show_dialog
    @dialog ||= self.create_dialog
    @dialog.add_action_callback("ready") { |action_context|
      self.update_dialog
      nil
    }
    @dialog.add_action_callback("accept") { |action_context, value|
      self.update_material(value)
      @dialog.close
      nil
    }
    @dialog.add_action_callback("cancel") { |action_context, value|
      @dialog.close
      nil
    }
    @dialog.add_action_callback("save") { |action_context, value|
      self.update_material(value)
      request = Sketchup::Http::Request.new("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/projectStatus/save", Sketchup::Http::POST )
      request.start do |request, response|
        puts "body: #{response.body}"
      end
      nil
    }
    @dialog.show
  end
```

I want send the the post request something like this:

```
{
    "length": "11",
     "width": "12",
    "volume": "168"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have 2 methods:

**JAVASCRIPT INSIDE THE PAGE**

-> send a request in javascript directly inside your webdialog as in a normal html page. For exemple, if you use Jquery:

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
.....
<body>
<button id="save">save</button>
</body>

<script>
$( "#save" ).click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/projectStatus/save",
    data: {
      "length": "11",
       "width": "12",
      "volume": "168"
  },
    success: success,
    dataType: dataType
  });
});

</script>
</html>
```

**IN RUBY**
inside your ruby by removing Sketchup ruby code, by removing Sketchup and add

```
  Sketchup::require 'net/http'
  ....
  @dialog.add_action_callback("save") { |action_context, value|
      self.update_material(value)
      uri = URI("http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/projectStatus/sav")
      result_json = Net::HTTP.post(uri,{
        "length": "11",
        "width": "12",
        "volume": "168"
   })
    result = JSON.parse(result_json)

  }
```

Hope it's help